# Android: Possible to have multiple distinct Shared Preferences per app?

Tags: android

Is it possible to have multiple Shared Preferences per app? If you create a PreferenceActivity, the values by default are persisted to /data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/shared_prefs/[PACKAGE_NAME]_ 
preferences.xml

Is there a way to have multiple such files and which one to use for a given PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sure:

If you use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` it will create the file you mention.

If you use `context.getSharedPreferences("OtherPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` it will create a file (and SharedPreferences object) in /data/data/[PACKAGE_NAME]/shared_prefs/OtherPrefs.xml.

Comment: @dhaag23 do you know if its possible to use the same PreferenceActivity from two different sharedpreferences xml files?